# forward-sexp confusion

Tags: regular-expressions, formatting, sexp

The following code is an excerpt from the elisp tutorial, section 14.6.

```
(while (re-search-forward "^(defun" nil t)
    (setq lengths-list (cons (count-words-in-defun) lengths-list)))
```

Placing the cursor just before the code and executing (forward-sexp) will fail, because of the <kbd>(</kbd> symbol imbedded in the regexp `"^(defun"`.  My **ugly** remedy is below:

```
(setq my-regexp (concat "^" (char-to-string 40) "defun"))
(while (re-search-forward my-regexp nil t)
    (setq lengths-list (cons (count-words-in-defun) lengths-list)))
```

Is there a **less ugly** approach?  Alternatively, is there a *wrapper* for (forward-sexp) that provides optional arguments to ignore imbedded quotes and ignore imbedded comments (e.g. `;...`)?

If not, I will reference this posting as a feature request for both forward-sexp and backward-sexp.

Comment: WFM in `27.0.50` and probably earlier too. What is your `emacs-version`?

Comment: `forward-sexp` does the right thing, but only if you're using the right major-mode. since how to skip strings and comments is something that depends on the language.

Comment: @sds I just confirmed Stefan's comment.  I am using emacs 25.3.1, and the problem exists in text mode but is resolved okay in lisp mode.

Comment: see also my comment to the answer from sds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [`forward-sexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html) works just fine for me on the code in question (in Emacs `27.0.50`), the standard workaround is to add a single backslash, e.g., `"^\(defun "`.

One place where it actually *is* needed is when doc string contains code.
Emacs uses a simple heuristic ("line starting with a paren starts a function") for [`beginning-of-defun`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Defuns.html) and code like this:

```
(defun foo (...)
  "Blah blah...
Sample code:
(foo 1 2 3)
Blah"
  (actual code))
```

breaks the heuristic.

The [standard workaround](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Left-Margin-Paren.html) is to add a backslash:

```
(defun foo (...)
  "Blah blah...
Sample code:
\(foo 1 2 3)
Blah"
  (actual code))
```

Comment: Just discovered that the problem is mode specific; I keep my elisp tutorial notes in elisp_notes_todo.txt.  Per my comment above (reply to Stefan), I can resolve my problem via `M-x lisp-mode`, then `forward-sexp`, then `M-x text-mode`.  Assuming that your answer *works*, **it will be helpful** for an *unbalanced parenthesis* in the doc string.  Thanks

Comment: my bad.  actually, applying `forward-sexp` on the **first** section of code in sds' answer works okay, **in lisp mode.** Experimenting, I just discovered that `forward-sexp` **also** works okay in lisp mode when the doc string has an *unbalanced parenthesis*, so my previous comment is **flawed.**  So, since temporarily changing to lisp-mode seems to resolve all `forward-sexp` problems, sds' approach can **apparently** be restricted to `beginning-of-defun` problems.